# AFNetworkingError on IOS SDK Drupal

Tags: ios, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having issue loggingout of my Localhost which is implemented by using Drupal 7 
I've configured everything as mentioned by https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk 
First of all, I wanna thank kylebrowning for spending his huge amount of time to create this awesome SDK. 
The problem that i'm facing is that I can login just fine, but I failed logout. 
I NSLog to see the error of the code. 
Here is the error that shows on the out put tab. 
I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links 
here is what inside my http below, "192.168.1.24/drupal/rest/user/logout"

Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x8c4d6c0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=["CSRF validation failed"], AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey= { URL: ">" http:// }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= { URL: http:// } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 26;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 27 Mar 2014 09:10:32 GMT";
    Etag = "\"1395911432\"";
    Expires = "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=98";
    "Last-Modified" = "Thu, 27 Mar 2014 09:10:32 +0000";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.5.3";
    "Set-Cookie" = "SESS0fd8593946486e6ecd06721db47d9fe9=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly";
    Vary = Accept;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.3";
} }}

Here is my code

```
#import "AfterLoginViewController.h"
#import "DIOSUser.h"
#import "DIOSSession.h"
#import "DIOSSystem.h"
@interface AfterLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation AfterLoginViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (IBAction)LogOut {
    [DIOSUser
     userLogoutWithSuccessBlock:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response)
    {
        [self alertStatus:@"Logout Successful" :@"Sign Out Successful" :0];
         NSLog(@"Logout Successful");
         [self alertStatus:@"LogOut Successful" :@"LogOut is completed" :0];
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToLogin" sender:self];
         /* Handle successful operation here */
    }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err)
    {
         [self alertStatus:@"LogOut Failed" :@"LogOut failed Please Try Again !!!" :0 ];
         NSLog (@"Signout failed");
         NSLog (@"%@", err);
    }
     ];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I would be very appreciated if someone can help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find in DIOSSystem class
this method

```
+ (void)systemConnectwithSuccess: (void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)) success
    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)) failure {
DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
[session getCSRFTokenWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {...}
```

and check if in getCSRFTokenWithSuccess the token is setted correctly like:

```
- (void)getCSRFTokenWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                   failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/services/session/token", [[DIOSSession sharedSession] baseURL]]]];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/plain"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *aCsrfToken = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseObject bytes]];
    [[DIOSSession sharedSession] setCsrfToken:aCsrfToken];
    if (success != nil) {
        success(operation, responseObject);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [DIOSSession logRequestFailuretoConsole:operation withError:error];
    if (failure != nil) {
        failure(operation, error);
    }
}];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/plain", @"application/json", nil];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

}

Finally use this , works for me:

```
 [DIOSUser
 userMakeSureUserIsLoggedOutWithSucess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
     NSLog(@"LogOut success!");

 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) {
     NSLog(@"LogOut error: %@",err);

 }
 ];
```